# How can I stretch an iframe to cover its parent element without CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a JavaScript or jQuery solution to stretch or shrink the child element to cover the container using px width and height.

```html
<div style="width:300px; height:713px;"><iframe  ratio="4:1 || 4:3 || 16:9 || ..." ></iframe></div>


<div style="width:713px; height:300px;"><iframe  ratio="4:1 || 4:3 || 16:9 || ..." ></iframe></div>
```

Comment: By "cover", you mean, fill 100% of the width/height? And, generally, most CSS solutions could be applied inline with JS if that's absolutely a requirement.

Comment: Does this not work with `width:100%;` and `height:100%;` ? Percentage values like that are relative to the parent. You can click the `<>` button to make a runnable snippet to illustrate your point.

Comment: What have you tried? Note that your closing iframe tags are faulty (misspelled).

Comment: `style="width: 300px; height: 713px"` *is* CSS.

Comment: As is the result when using JavaScript's `style` interface to change those values. It's good to want things, but Stack Overflow isn't here to do your work for you. We can help you if you're trying to get something done and need some help, but if you want someone to write code based on requirements, I suggest hiring a developer.

Comment: NOTE::: I said "without CSS". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out:

w and h can be just the ratios 16:9, 4:3, etc or the actual size of the curent video
cw is the container width and ch is the container height
you can fill the container with fill or fit the video into the container with "fit"

```
function vidratios(w, h, cw, ch, tp='fill') {
    var ratw = cw / w;
    var rath = ch / h;
    if(tp == 'fit'){
    var ratio = ratw < rath ? ratw : rath;
    } else {
    var ratio = ratw > rath ? ratw : rath;
    }
    var nw = w * ratio;
    var nh = h * ratio;
    var retarr = {
        'cw': nw,
        'ch': nh,
        'rat': ratio
    };

    return retarr;
}
```